# app crashes after pressing positive button in alert dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

whenever i am pressing my positive button of alert dialog by simply writing toast it is working fine and toast is visible but if i am performing any action on positive button then the action is getting performed but in the meanwhile my app also crashes.

- In my app basically after clicking positive button it has to send on link of forgotten password to respective mail id.
- code is working fine for sending link of forgotten password.
- whenever i am pressing positive button of alert dialogue i am able to get the link in my mail but i don't know why my app crashes just after hitting the positive button of alert dialogue

> disire:- I just want to run my app smoothly that is after pressing positive button it should show the required toast message and just close the alert dialogue by performing the required action.

below is the error shown in logcat.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed:
 {com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
```

code snippet is like this.

```
sendingPassword=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogue_layout,null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("forget password")
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    forgetEmail=view.findViewById(R.id.forgetpasswordarea);

                    sendingPassword.sendPasswordResetEmail(forgetEmail.getText().toString().trim())
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"check your email for link",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }

            });


    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: You need to provide stacktrace of crash?

Comment: it is very bulky